# Seam where longitude wraps around in matplotlib/cartopy Mollweide projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf, cartopy, python-xarray

I am plotting some NETCDF data, handled by xarray in Matplotlib using a Cartopy wrapper for the map projections. When I produce a filled contour plot (contourf), I end up with a 'seam' at longitude zero (where my data longitudes begin and end). Is there an in-line way to interpolate between longitude[-1] and longitude[0], perhaps by treating the data as periodic or something?

Please see the attached graphic for an example:

[image]

Comment: If you can not find a way to fix this with your current setup, an alternative may be to try Iris. http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/gallery.html

Answer (score 2):

You should add a cyclic point to your data array and its longitude coordinate using the `add_cyclic_point` function: http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.16/cartopy/util/util.html#cartopy.util.add_cyclic_point.